# How to generate APK and IPA using Anroid studio for Ionc Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, apk, ipa

[image]I have  ionic Angular code , I have installed Anroid stuido setup. I have no idea how to  generate APK and IPA from the code . I have tried referring to some websites but it seems little confusing from the documentation . If any one has experience in this , please  assist me . Thanks in advance

I have added the path from the  ionic code anroid but in the Anroid studio ,I couldn't see the option to build APK as you could see  in the screen shot

Comment: Have you generated Android and ios platforms with ionic?

Comment: For generating an IPA to my knowledge you always require a MAC running Xcode.

Comment: I have generated Anroid and ios platforms  with ionic

Answer (score 1):

Android studio is only for APK. You need a mac to do IPA for Apple.

The docs provide how to do both:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android

Answer (score 1):

To generate IPA you need a MAC system for iPhone Apple and to generate APK you need to follow this link to setup without any error then you can build the APK for Android so you need to setup cordova with Java & Gradle so please follow this like to help you out - https://ionicframework.com/docs/v6/developing/android